# Getx gives error :[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am new to getx,previously I am using provider state management tool.I am using getx as a state management tool.The active tab index is change,but UI is not change when not using Obx to listen the change.But when i use Obx to listen the chageit gives an error:

```
  **Exception has occurred.
            "      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
                  You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
                  If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
                  or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
                  (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
                  If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
          "**
```

controller code

```
class myController extends GetxController {
  RxInt _currentIndex = 0.obs;
  void handleActiveTab(int index) {
    activetab = index;
    print("object: $activetab");
  }
}
```

I have three pages and want to change page when user tap on bottomnavbar.
page handler code:

```
class PageHandler extends StatelessWidget {
  PageHandler({super.key});
  myController controller = Get.put(myController());
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    const HomePage(),
    const AnalyzeDataPage(),
    const AccountPage()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:Obx(()=> _pages[controller.activetab]),
        bottomNavigationBar: const bottomBar());
  }
}
```

pages

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(title: "Homepage"),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: const Column(
            children: [
              Income(), 
              Expense(), 
              IncomeExpenseChart(),   
          ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AccountPage> createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Comment: You try to observe `activeTab` which is not an observable variable.

Comment: Convert your list into `RxList `

Answer (score 2):

try these changes:

**Controller Class:**

```
class MyController extends GetxController {
  final RxInt _currentIndex = 0.obs;

  int get activeTab => _currentIndex.value;

  void handleActiveTab(int index) {
    _currentIndex.value = index;
  }
}
```

**PageHandler:**

```
class PageHandler extends StatelessWidget {
  PageHandler({super.key});
  MyController controller = Get.put(MyController());
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.cyan,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: _pages[controller.activeTab]),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: controller.activeTab,
          onTap: (index) {
            controller.handleActiveTab(index);
          },
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business), label: "Business"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: "School"),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Demo gif]

Comment: no,only index is changing but not UI

Comment: check my answer. I've added demo gif to show it works.

Comment: yes,it works .Thanks

Comment: glad to help. please mark my answer as accepted.